Incorrect connection string parameter when running SSIS package
I have an SSIS package which I built in VS 2022 then deployed locally to a SQL Server 2019 instance.
I pass the connection strings for both source and destination databases as parameters in the parent package, which then bind to parameters in the child packages, this works fine when both the source and destination databases are on the local instance.  As soon as I change the parameter to point to a different server/db, it fails and says the parameter is incorrect.  I know the details are correct as I can log on with them, does anything obvious look wrong with this?
Data Source=tcp:mysite.database.windows.net,1111;Initial Catalog=MyBd;Provider=SQLNCLI11;User ID=MyUser;Password=mypass123;Auto Translate=false;

Here is the exact error:

Package1:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80070057.
COM error object information is available.  Source: "Package1"  error code: 0x80070057  Description: "The SSIS Runtime has failed to enlist the OLE DB connection in a distributed transaction with error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect.".
".

The package is fairly basic, using a load of child package it does this:
Deletes rows from temporary tables in the destination DB
Copies data from tables in the source to the destination
Deletes rows from the main tables in the destination
Copies from the temp tables to the main tables in destination
The parent package has TransactionOption set as 'Required'
The child packages are set to 'Supported'
I also made a copy of the package where the parent and child TransactionOption settings are all 'Not Supported', and this gave the same result.

"the parameter is incorrect" isn't an SSIS error I can think of. What are the actual error(s) you're getting?

Why are you still using SQLNCLI as well? That was deprecated in 2012 and discontinued in 2014; you should have long start using MSOLEDBSQL or similar by now.

This was copied from an existing connection string to the database, it's in another organisation.  The connection works as is but yes I do agree with you.  Exact error now included in post.

Making dtc work is hard, at least i never figure out how to do properly. Might wanna try avoiding transactions across servers but that might not be possible, what does your package do?

The error has nothing to do with your connection string.
The error is a DTC error "The SSIS Runtime has failed to enlist the OLE DB connection in a distributed transaction with error 0x80070057".
Ensure that DTC is running on the target server, or don't use transactions.

Actually, DTC is running on the target server so it's not that
